# Selecting rows with unique field values in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have these columns for table `comments`:

```
id
content
add_date
uid
school_id
```

Rows can have the same school_id.

I want to select the latest data according to add_date, but only **1 row per school_id** (no duplicate for `school_id`) with  limit of 10.

I've tried many codes already and its not working for me.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This is what we call `Greatest N per Group`. You can achieved this by putting into a subquery so it can be joined against the non-grouped table (`comments`).
Try this:

```
SELECT  c.*
FROM
        (
            SELECT school_id, MAX(add_date) maxDate
            FROM comments
            GROUP BY school_id
        ) x INNER JOIN comments c
            ON  x.school_id = c.school_ID AND
                x.maxDate = c.add_date
ORDER BY x.maxDate desc
LIMIT 10
```

Comment: Probably want to add ORDER BY maxDate DESC LIMIT 10 to the subquery x.  This will result in only the 10 most recent posts being pulled from comments after the aggregation.  Otherwise, if there are more than 10 schools, extra lookups are done.

Comment: the OP asked for `select the latest data according to add_date`

Comment: Yes, and ordering desc in the subquery will find the most recent 10 by add_date.  You don't need more than the 10 most recent records from x.

Answer (score 0):

```
select C.ID, C.Content, t1.MaxDate as [add_date], C.uid, t1.school_id
from (selet school_id, max(add_Date) as 'MaxDate'
from comments
group by school_id) T1
inner join comments C on T1.school_id = C.school_id and C.add_Date= T1.MaxDate
LIMIT 10
```

If you want to choose which 10 `rows` return, add an `order by`, or a `Where` clause

Answer (score 0):

```
select c1.*
  from comments c1
 where add_date = (select max(add_date) from comments c2 where c2.school_id =c1.school_id)
 order by add_date desc
 limit 10
```

create indexes on comments(add_date) and comments(school_id, add_date)

Comment: The other provided solutions for the problem will have to scan the entire comments table and will not scale as the table grows.  This solution will read the minimum number of required rows.